# Set out of the disk region to white?

Tags: image-processing

The image is generated by the code below:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
ImageTransformation[img, If[Norm[# - 0.5] < 0.5, #, {-0.1, -0.1}] &]
```

[image]

How can I set the background from black to white, and it will only be applied on the region out of the disk?

Comment: add the option `Padding -> 1`?

Comment: That works! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageTransformation[img, If[Norm[# - 0.5] < 0.5, #, {-0.1, -0.1}] &, 
 Background -> White, Masking -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ImageTransformation[img, If[Norm[# - 0.5] < 0.5, #, {-0.1, -0.1}] &, Padding-> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Could `RemoveBackground` be used here? I was wondering, why you didn't use the built-in function.

Comment: Excellent point @Syed. (Looks like I assumed OP wanted to get the desired result directly using `ImageTransformation`)